# Eclipse m2eclipse not picking up "provided" transitive dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

Trying to get [Roboguice](https://github.com/emmby/roboguice) working in Eclipse which contains 2 Maven projects, Astroboy and Roboguice (let's call them A and B where A depends on B). My problem is that unit tests in A which work fine in Maven give compile errors in Eclipse because it can't find Junit. Junit is declared in A's pom as a provided dependency, as below. I did tell Eclipse that project A depends on B by adding B to A's build path/projects.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I got it to work temporarily by changing the scope to test (then doing a mvn install and maven/update project on A), but what must I do to have it find Junit by itself?

Comment: JUnit must be test-scoped. Provided dependencies ARE NOT transitive.

Comment: Why must they be test-scoped?  Why does this work in maven but not eclipse?

Comment: JUnit must be test-scoped because it is test library. Provided scope tells Maven that classes in this artifact are accessible in the runtime. So, Maven will not package it to the target (jar with dependencies or war). This scope is often used with servlet containers or various "wrappers". I mean the situations where your code is plugged into a bigger system with it's own classpath. Regarding to the Eclipse/Maven problems i only can say that is not ideal. Maybe it is just another bug, or, maybe, Eclipse runs test with it's own runner and JUnit is not accessible there because of scope.